# Django application: UserPassesTestMixin to verify user is the author of posts before allowing access to view?

Tags: django

The goal of my application is to allow users to create posts for their own private account viewing.

I'm using a class based view to show the current logged in user their posts. In order to prevent users from being able to see other user's posts, I have a UserPassesTestMixin test_func that iterates through the query set and checks to make sure they are the author of those posts.

The problem that I'm having is when there are no posts to display, I receive a 404 error code stating that there is nothing matching the query. I want it to still display the page even when there are no posts available. When I only use the get_queryset function, it works and displays my template without posts, but without having the UserPassesTestMixin and test_func, a user could enter another person's username into the URL and be able to view the other person's account/posts.

Here is the code for this class based view in my views.py file:

```
class UserSessionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    model = session
    template_name = 'programmerjournal/user_sessions.html'
    context_object_name = 'sessions'
    paginate_by = 24

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return session.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_added')

    def test_func(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        posts = get_list_or_404(session, author=user)
        for post in posts:
            if self.request.user == post.author:
               return True
            return False
```

Comment: I find it a bit odd that there is a parameter `username`. Your url thus contains a `<username>` parameter that is not per se the logged in user?

Comment: I'm using the built in Django User model which automatically contains the username attribute so that the user has something to sign in with.

Comment: normally in Django there is no `username` URL parameter, if you do not specify one yourself. Furthermore the authentication middleware will simply add a `.user` attribute to the request that contains the logged in user, which is an object of the user model.

Comment: I'm still a bit new to Django and all of its concepts so I wasn't sure exactly what you were suggesting at first. After reading over your additional responses and explanation I now understand. You provided an excellent answer that helped me grasp a Django concept that I didn't fully understand before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I only use the `get_queryset` function, it works and displays my template without posts, but without having the `UserPassesTestMixin` and `test_func`, a user could enter another person's username into the URL and be able to view the other person's account/posts.

In fact even with a `UserPassesTestMixin` in this case a person can enter another account and get access, since you work with the `username`, and never take into account the logged in user at all.

If you don't want to display posts of another user, you should not use a `<username>` URL parameter. But make use of the `request.user` that contains the logged in user:

```
class UserSessionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = session
    template_name = 'programmerjournal/user_sessions.html'
    context_object_name = 'sessions'
    paginate_by = 24

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        ).order_by('-date_added')
```

Here `request.user` will thus contain the logged in user. It thus makes no sense to store the username in the URL since indeed users can tamper with the URL.

Comment: I updated the view using your suggestion and it works perfectly! I will go in and change the URL paths to exclude the username as well. Thank you so much!